# ajax call taking much time in internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

The below jQuery post take lot time in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome. The method is working instantly in other pages. This method is common to all pages.

```js
function checkSession() {
  debugger;
  var checkSessiontUrl = '@Url.Action("CheckSession", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)';
  var logoutUrl = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Home", null , Request.Url.Scheme)';
  noProgressLoaderRequired = true;
  $.ajax({
    url: checkSessiontUrl,
    data: {
      uniqueId: '@Session["UniqueId"]'
    },
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data != true) {
        debugger;
        isInsideApplication = true;
        window.location.href = logoutUrl;
      }
      noProgressLoaderRequired = false;
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      //alert('Ajax failure');
      isInsideApplication = true;
      window.location.href = logoutUrl;
      noProgressLoaderRequired = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's likely the issue resides on the server not in the js. How long does the server take to respond?

Comment: this script is added in layout page. It is not happened for every Page only in Particular page and also in Internet Explorer only. In Chrome it is loaded Instantly.